# Add Value without key to JSON

Tags: java, json, jackson, objectmapper

Im Trying to achive a Json structure like this:

```
[
    "Test1",
    {
        "name": "testName",
        "phone": "123456"
    }
]
```

but when i output my testObjectList i dont really know how to add the "Test1" String.

At the moment i create my Json Output like this:

```
public class TestClass {
    String name;
    String phone;

    public TestClass(String name, String phone) {
        super();
        this.name = name;
        this.phone = phone;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public String getPhone() {
        return phone;
    }
}
```

```
public class TestProjectApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonMappingException, JsonProcessingException {
        var testObject = new TestClass("testName", "123456");
        var testObjectList = new ArrayList();
        testObjectList.add(testObject);
        var mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        System.out.println(mapper.readTree(mapper.writeValueAsString(testObjectList)));
    }
}
```

The output looks like this:

```
[
    {
        "name": "testName",
        "phone": "123456"
    }
]
```

But how do i add "Test1" ?

Comment: Add `"Test1"` to `testObjectList`.

Comment: @Stultuske it looks invalid, but its actually allowed to have values as array elements.

Answer (score 0):

Easy way to do it - use [Gson library](https://github.com/google/gson)

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
String json = gson.toJson(testObjectList);
```